# postgis_tiger_geocoder create extension fails with geometry does not exist error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgis, rails-postgresql

I have a `rails` app and I use `postgis` in my app to store the spatial data and now I would like to make use of the `reverse geocode` function in postgis and there by looked for the options and found that it needs the `tiger_geocoder` extension to be installed. But when I try to install that in the existing app, I get the following error

> ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist

So, I have been trying for the past 1.5 days to resolve the issue by reinstalling postgis and all other steps that I came through but could not find any solution to resolve this.

And another thing I noticed is that I could able to install it when I simply run psql and install that extension but when it comes to the db in my app, I could not install it. I have run the following command to look if the geometry exist

> set search_path = postgis,public;
>
> \d geometry_columns

and that returned the following result

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: That error generally indicates that PostGIS isn't installed _in the database you're using_. Exactly what steps did you take leading up to the error message (with code examples)? Were you installing the geocoder from an extension or from source? If you `psql` into the database where you're attempting to install the geocoder, and you run `SELECT postgis_version();`, what happens?

Comment: I have postgis installed definitely because when I tried to create extension, it showed that the extension is already present and there by confirmed that we had the postgis. But looking into more deeply, we found that postgis is not installed properly. So, I tried to drop the extension and recreating the postgis made the tiger extension work now. Thanks anyways.